# How do you model & facilitate this functionality in DDD?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, domain-driven-design

I'm working on a .NET + EF Core system which uses clean architecture, CQRS and follows Domain Driven Design principles.

To describe my problem, let's use a car dealership as a metaphor.

I have 2 bounded contexts, let's refer to them as Sales and Service. I have a 3rd context called User.

When a vehicle is sold, such code is executed within the Sales context - and the 'current user' would be needed to store such information like who sold the vehicle.

When a vehicle is serviced, similarly, information stored on a User model would include a 'limit' as to whether the user can authorise certain repairs to be conducted on a vehicle, or whether they would need to consult a supervisor if not.

The User domain object is defined within the User domain, however as some of our codebase currently has it implemented, this object is also referenced in places like the Sales and Service contexts, like such an example:

```cs
public class VehicleService {

// instance properties

  public void AuthoriseService(User user) {

  // ... Code to check if service can be authorised by user

  }
}
```

Is it acceptable to do so? Should each context have their own User definitions, and unique infrastructure to populate them despite them accessing the same table as the User context?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it is not good to share entities from one context into another context it is better to have separate user entity in different context.
Bounded contexts should be as much as possible loose coupled
for example you have Context A and B so the User entity in context A could be different than in context B check this [article](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/BoundedContext.html)
In the same time to communicate between the context you need to use events especially if you are using CQRS. So when Car sold the event CarSold should be send and all the services who interested into this event should handle it by updating their domain. Imagine all your bounded context it is in separate micro-services. how would you implement it when you don't have shared code base

Answer (score 0):

With CQRS design, you will have some overlap.  This is to be expected.  Your cross-domain objects can be defined separately and used concurrently in different domains but it is best to use an interface so that you can change the underlying implementation between domains if necessary.

Comment: So in this implementation, you'd suggest having an interface for my domain classes - like an IUser?

Comment: @jarodsmk Yes, that's correct.